# Batch Script to shut down computer after 1 minute

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a batch script so than when I run that batch script, it will automatically shutdown my computer after 1 minute. Please ! help me to create it.

Comment: What have **you** tried? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask.

Comment: first of all, what system are using?

Comment: Err.. no.  You don't even tell us what OS you're running.  Have you considered Googling?

Comment: I am using Windows 7. I have google and found something like this
echo shutdown -s -f -t 60 but it didn't work at all

Comment: Don't type `echo shutdown -s -f -t 60` in one line! This ... `shutdown -s -f -t 60` should work fine

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure the use of it, but here you go:

```
@echo off
shutdown /t 60
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

"C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe" -s -t 60

-s Shutdown local PC

-t in 60 Seconds